# Apply dummyvar function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, double, dummy-data

I have two distinct double variables with one column and 30000 rows each. For instance:

```
A=[53
76
41
74
34
237
43…]

B= [1985
1985
1985
…
1986
1986
…
2013…]
```

If I do:

```
size(unique(A),1)
ans =261
size(unique(B),1)
ans = 27
```

But when I do:

```
D1=dummyvar(A)
```

I get a double matrix with 355 columns and 30000 rows of 1s and 0s, meaning that Matlab has identified 355 different dummies instead of 261.

and,

```
D2=dummyvar(B)
```

I get as well, a double with 2012 columns, what is also incorrect.

Matlab is identifying more dummies in my categorical columns as expected, so I must be doing something wrong, but I don’t know what because previously this formula worked for me. Can someone help me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of columns of `dummyvar(A)` is `max(A)`. This example should clarify:

```
>> A = [1;2;2;5]
A =
     1
     2
     2
     5
>> unique(A)
ans =
     1
     2
     5
>> dummyvar(A)
ans =
     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
```

If you want to avoid those all-zero columns, use third output of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to "remove the gaps" in `A`, and *then* apply `dummyvar`:

```
>> A = [1;2;2;5]
A =
     1
     2
     2
     5
>> [~, ~, uA] = unique(A)
uA =
     1
     2
     2
     3
>> dummyvar(uA)
ans =
     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
```

Comment: I understand your answer and maybe I have formulated my question in the wrong way. But my pont is, if I have a variable that (let's see the example of B) has 1 column and 30000 rows with values from 1983 to 2012, why would I get 2012 dummies instead of 30 dummies, which is the number of different values we observe in B?

Comment: @user3557054 You don't understand the answer, or else you wouldn't still be confused. The `dummyvar` function assumes that you have variables labeled from `1` to `max(B)` - but that there aren't any observations of the variables `1` to `1982` (the first 1982 columns of the result will all be set to zero).

Comment: @user3557054 See edited answer. Maybe second part is what you want

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I understand the answer, but it does not solve my problem. What is the point of having so manny dummies if I could only have 30. I have to delete them manually? Like this I will get an error in my regression because I have too many dummies. So I just thought there would be a way for Matlab to recognize 'useless' dummies so to say.

Comment: @user3557054 That's what my updated answer does. Have you checked it out?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes yes it solves exactly my problem, I just tried it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this function will be useful

```
function [result, columnNames] = dummyvarSmart(x)
    [columnNames, ~, indices] = unique(x);
    result = dummyvar(indices);
    columnNames = transpose(columnNames);
end
```

You can use it like this

```
>> B = sort(1983 + randi(30, 1000, 1));
>> min(B)
ans =
        1984
>> max(B)
ans =
        2013
>> [result, names] = dummyvarSmart(B);
>> size(result)
ans =
        1000        30
>> names(1:5)
ans =
        1984        1985        1986        1987        1988
```